# The posterior covariance matrix with missing data

Tags: bayesian, missing-data

Let $X \sim N(0, \Sigma)$ be a multivariate normal vector, and let our prior for $\Sigma$ be inverse-Wishart: $\Sigma\sim IW(v,V)$.
The posterior for $\Sigma$ given $X$ is [also inverse-Wishart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#When_likelihood_function_is_a_continuous_distribution):
$$\Sigma | X = x \sim  IW(1 + v, V + x'x).$$

I'm interested in the case in which we observe only some elements of $X$. I.e., we observe $X_c \sim N(0, \Sigma_c)$, where $\Sigma_c$ is a submatrix of $\Sigma$. The posterior density for the full covariance matrix $\Sigma$ given an observation $X_c$ will be
$$
p(\Sigma| X_c = x_c)
 \propto |\Sigma_c|^{-\frac{1}{2}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} x_c' \Sigma_c^{-1} x_c\right)f(\Sigma),
$$
where $f(\Sigma)$ is the prior density of $\Sigma$.

Is there a prior on $Σ$ such that this posterior is conjugate for any set of observed elements of $X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I haven't been able to find a conjugate prior, I believe the following MCMC algorithm will suffice:

In each iteration $r$: 
($r.1$) draw the missing elements ${X_{-c}}^r$ given $X_c, Σ^{r-1}$, 
($r.2$) draw $Σ^r$ given $X_c, {X_{-c}}^r$.

Step ($r.1$) just requires drawing from a [Normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions) while step ($r.2$) can draw from an Inverse-Wishart as described in the original question.

I believe that $Σ^r$ should converge in distribution to $Σ | X_c$.